# Right Align Span issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

So i have a set of spans that needs to be right-aligned which i got it working using `float:right` . However when i try to use multiple `div` with those spans they all end up in the same line. How can i get it to align by `div` under which the spans are in? Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1715mk0y/

```
.roption{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    float:right;  
}
```

Comment: sorry...didnt get your question..could you please explain it a bit more clearly..

Comment: So if you have a look at the fiddle you will see the contents of the first div and the second div overlap. I need the div to be displayed one below the other i.e second div below first div.

Comment: That is due to the `position:absolute` given for the `outer-div`..see http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/1715mk0y/11/

Comment: Yes but then the alignment of the spans gets messed up. I need them to be right aligned one below the other.

Comment: Are you specific that you want `span` instead of `div` ?

Comment: Actually that doesn't matter as long as the required alignment is same

Comment: is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/1715mk0y/12/) what you want?

Comment: Great. Now i have the divs in order. However the second div format is messed up now. As it has tyo be something like this http://jsfiddle.net/1715mk0y/13/

Comment: Check my edited answer @prem89

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/1715mk0y/12/)

I've added a `div` like

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

after each of the floated `div`s, which clears the float property assigned to the divs using

```
clear:both;
```

Red more about it in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear)

**UPDATE**

If you want to show any of the divs in the same line, then please dont add the clearfix div before them..See the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/1715mk0y/15/)

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thanks :)